# MongoDB Aggregate - How to implement match and lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

I need to get the data from two collections (expenses, accounts). The data must be between the given date range and amount range.
**date, amount, currency, type** is in **Expenses** collection and **accountId** is in **account** collection as **_id**.
I tried the following query but it's not returning anything.

```js
const response = await Expense.aggregate( [
   { $match: { 
       $and: [
           {
               currency: "1",
               expenseType: "1"
           },
           {
               date: {
                   $gte: new Date(date.value.from) , $lte: new Date(date.value.to) 
               },
               amount: {
                   $gt: parseFloat(amount.value.from) , $lt: parseFloat(amount.value.to)
               }
           }
       ],               
   } },
   {
       $lookup: {
           from: "accounts",
           localField: "accountId",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "account"
       }
   }
] )
```

This is the schema of expenses collection:

[image: This is the schema of expenses collection]

Document of expense collection:

[image]

Document of account collection:

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide the sample data for both collections? Meanwhile, does `type` field exist in the Expense document? as I see the field doesn't exist in your Expense schema. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question. As you have asked, the type field is expenseType. and I apologise for the late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the attached `expense` document, the `amount` field was a `String` type but **not** a `Number` type.

> Data

```
amount: "20000"
```

> Schema

```
amount: {
  type: Number,
  required: true
}
```

You should revise your `Expense` document in MongoDB with your schema.

---

From your Aggregation Query, you need to convert `amount` from String to Decimal to compare.

**Solution 1: With `$expr`**

```
db.expense.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          currency: "1",
          expenseType: "1"
        },
        {
          date: {
            $gte: new Date(date.value.from), 
            $lte: new Date(date.value.to) 
          },
          
        },
        {
          $expr: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  {
                    "$toDecimal": "$amount"
                  },
                  parseFloat(amount.value.from)
                ]
              },
              {
                $lt: [
                  {
                    "$toDecimal": "$amount"
                  },
                  parseFloat(amount.value.to)
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "accounts",
      localField: "accountId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "account"
    }
  }
])
```

[Solution 1 on Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_CceozUh_d3)

---

**Solution 2: Add `$set` as first stage**

```
db.expense.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      amount: {
        "$toDecimal": "$amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          currency: "1",
          expenseType: "1"
        },
        {
          date: {
            $gte: new Date(date.value.from),
            $lte: new Date(date.value.to)
          },
          amount: {
            $gt: parseFloat(amount.value.from),
            $lt: parseFloat(amount.value.to)
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "accounts",
      localField: "accountId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "account"
    }
  }
])
```

[Solution 2 on Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ySrMypYUrJo)